# If I compile with Intel compilers, will I be able to use the results after my license expires?

Tags: licensing, intel, icc, intel-mkl

Suppose I compile libraries or other software packages with Intel compilers (e.g. icc, ifort) and related Intel libraries (MKL, TBB, etc.). If, after my Intel license expires, I want to compile things that depend on the previously compiled software, will I be able to compile and use them, even though my license expired? Will the second compilation process not be able to read or link to the previously compiled software? Or, if it compiles successfully, will it produce an error saying that my license needs to be renewed?

More concrete example:

- **Today:** I use `icc` and TBB to compile [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview).
- **Next Year (after license expires):** I try to compile and run [SuiteSparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) with `gcc`, which uses MKL and depends on METIS.

Is there any reason that this wouldn't work? Would the old libraries look up my current license status and find that it isn't working?

My reason for asking is that, while Intel provides the best compilers for my purposes, it is proprietary, and I want to develop code that will run in the future.

Comment: Ahh, the perils of using proprietary software..... :-( I'm loving GPL more and more right now.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Yes, if you have a commercial license

Long Answer: The Intel Compilers are not a standalone product but belong to the suites: Intel Parallel Studio and Intel System Studio. If you **buy** a license for one of those suites you get:

1. A usage license which is not time limited.
2. One year of support which means you can use premium support and access all updates that get released within one year.

There are also free licenses for academic research available. They may have also a usage limitation.